# access usb hard drive through terminal

Tags: command-line

I need to find a document which contains an specific word. The document is in my external hard drive but there are thousands of documents in it and I cannot find it. I think that using the command 'grep' I'll be able to find it, but when I try to access my external hard drive via the path cd /media/.... the terminal returns the message: "The file or directory doesn't exist". However, when I run the command 'ls' the hard drive is shown (in green) together with the other USB drives. Also, when I try to access the other usb drives there is no problem at all.

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the external hard drive?

Thank you very much in advance

Joan

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls` to your question, formatted as code? And also add the full command you entered that gave you the error message.

Answer (score 2):

So the process follows these steps:

Find your storage device in `/dev/`:

`sudo fdisk -l`

Which will probably print out a lot of info. You can find which `Device` by looking at the `Size` column that matches your usb (Be more discerning , perhaps looking at storage type, if you have more than one device with the same storage size).

Also, if the `Device` is `sdb` then you will use `sdb1`, if it's `sdc` you will use `sdc1` etc...

Next you want to create a folder for the USB to mount to, which is basically a fancy way of saying that the contents are copied to this folder so that they can be accessible as a folder in the filesystem.

`sudo mkdir /media/usb`

and for FAT `Type` devices you can mount with:

`sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/usb -o uid=1000`

or for NTFS `Type` devices, you can use:

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/usb -o uid=1000`

Now you can read and write to `/media/usb` and it will access your storage device.

When you are done, unmount the device:

`sudo umount /dev/sdb1`

and remove the temporary folder:

`sudo rm /media/usb -r`

Answer (score 0):

Unmount the USB flash drive, unplug it, and do

```
lsusb && dmesg | tail
```

Plug it back in and press **F3** then **Enter**

compare the results and identify where your flashdrive automounts to; let's say it automounts to **/dev/sdc1**

Then, perform this command (and change /dev/sdc1 to reflect where that USB drive automounts to)

```
sudo mkdir /media/usb && sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/usb
```

Then you should be able to grep the contents of /media/usb